# inserting a range within multiple filter criteria

Tags: python, pandas, range, logical-operators

I am trying to filter out naps by inserting logical operators on the duration of sleep minutes and hour of sleep. Applying the duration minimum works however when I insert the range of sleep hours, the code fails.The 'startsleep' column is an extract of the hour of a date time column.
Where am I going wrong with my code below?

```
 date_delta efficiency  has_sleep_data  datauuid    end_time    start_time  time_offset update_time create_time date    weekday day month   startsleep  wakeup  sleep_duration  duration_mins   powernaps   weekend
    0   0   92.663040   1.0 03f12ce0-9ade-5c74-9d57-686fd3966f2a    2018-03-08 05:30:00-04:00   2018-03-07 23:23:00-04:00   UTC-0400    2018-03-08 09:39:58.387000-04:00    2018-03-08 05:32:02.181000-04:00    2018-03-07  2   <built-in method date of datetime.datetime obj...   3   23  5   06:07:00    367.0   False   False
    1   1   87.788020   1.0 0419de25-ff8a-e425-0864-7e83b7f5d991    2018-02-25 09:28:00-04:00   2018-02-25 02:15:00-04:00   UTC-0400    2018-02-25 09:30:16.332000-04:00    2018-02-25 09:30:16.332000-04:00    2018-02-25  6   <built-in method date of datetime.datetime obj...   2   2   9   07:13:00    433.0   False   True
    2   2   90.026955   1.0 048b90e0-1e31-7875-337c-e9d8c24bea59    2018-06-02 06:49:00-03:00   2018-06-02 00:37:00-03:00   UTC-0300    2018-06-02 06:49:32.094000-03:00    2018-06-02 06:49:32.094000-03:00    2018-06-02  5   <built-in method date of datetime.datetime obj...   6   0   6   06:12:00    372.0   False   True
```

Error that I get adding the second logical operator below:

> TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

```
df_sleep['powernaps']=[(df_sleep.duration_mins<120) & (df_sleep.startsleep(10,23))]

df_sleep['powernaps']=[(df_sleep.duration_mins<120) & (df_sleep.startsleep(range(10,23)))]
```

I expect power naps to only return columns where duration criteria is `< 120 mins` and start sleep is between hours 10 a.m. and 23 p.m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears as you are trying to slice a `pd.Series` using parenthesis. You should be using brackets instead. I suggest you read on [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) to get a good understanding on how to index in pandas,

Also you cannot slice using a `range`, you would have to filter instead using both the lower and upper bounds as:

```
df_sleep['powernaps']=(df_sleep.duration_mins < 120) & 
                       (df_sleep.startsleep > 10) & 
                       (df_sleep.startsleep < 23)
```

Comment: Thank you, while the above works with only assignment of variable power naps to the code, it does not work if I try to add it as a power naps column, as per the original attempt. Gives me error: "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index"; would you know how to fix this?

Comment: Please provide some sample data so it is easier to see what the error is

Comment: Some data I meant, so I can give it a try myself

Comment: added the data head to the question - apologies for the legibility of it.